# How to Link Responsive.css with a custom wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

Hello i am new to wordpress . I have created a wordpress theme (for a website development) which has only Index , header , footer files and style.css now to i want to link Responsive.css with index.php page  which is stored in "/css/responsive.css"

I know that we can link style.css by: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" type="text/css">`

But i am confused that how i can link responsive css with page. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's `functions.php` file you need to add the following:

```
function so_38294160_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_38294160_enqueue_style' );
```

Please review [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts).

Keep in mind that you will need `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your theme. Read over [theme development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Plugin_API_Hooks) in the Codex.